# NuxtJS /Vue not firing scroll event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using Vue3 and NuxtJS,but it seems like scroll event wont fire. Nothing happens after I scroll,nor I don't have any errors

```
methods: {
    handleScroll () {
      console.log('scrolled')
      }
  },
created(){
   if(process.client){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    console.log(window)

}
  },
  destroyed () {
    if(process.client){
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `mounted()` if you want to use a client-only hook: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/#client (still the case with Nuxt3 if I'm not mistaken) You can see which event listener are plugged to your page in your devtools/browser console, check those.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your `process.client` is false.

I tried the code below and it works fine for me:

```js
  methods: {
    handleScroll() {
      console.log("scrolled");
    },
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    console.log(window);
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  },
</js>
```